# How to match the word exactly with regex?

Tags: java, regex, string, string-search

I might be asking this question incorrectly but what I would like to do is the following:

Given a large String which could be many 100s of lines long match and replace a word exactly and make sure it does not replace and match any part of any other String.

For example :

```
Strings to Find = Mac Apple Microsoft Matt Damon I.B.M. Hursley  
Replacement Strings = MacO AppleO MicrosoftO MattDamonP I.B.M.O HursleyL  
Input String (with some of the escape characters included for clarity) =  
"A file to test if it finds different\r\n  
bits and bobs like Mac, Apple and Microsoft.\n  
I.B.M. in Hursley does sum cool stuff!Wow look it's "Matt Damon"\r\n  
Testing something whichwillerrorMac"\n
```

OUTPUT

```
"A file to test if it finds different  
bits and bobs like MacO, AppleO and MicrosoftO.  
I.B.M.O in HursleyL do sum cool stuff!Wow look it's "Matt DamonP"  
Testing something whichwillerrorMac"
```

I have tried using Regex using word boundaries, although this picks up `'whichwhillerrorMacO'` on the last line.

I have also tried using the `StringTokenizer` class and various delimiters to try and replace words, but some of the words I am trying to replace contains these delimiters.

Is there a regex that would solve this problem?

Comment: How many different "strings to find" and "replacement strings" do you expect to have?  I think my answer would be the same either way but I thought I would check. :)

Comment: i still haven't solved this problem however but simply do an equality check for each word instead, it takes a long time on the downside though. Not sure such a problem like this can be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `\b(Mac|Apple)\b` with `\$1O\` will not touch `whichwillerrorMac` - it will match `whichwill-Mac` though.